# DELETAR COM LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Estou tendo um erro ao tentar executar este comando:

```
DELETE doacoes FROM doacoes LEFT OUTER JOIN animais ON animais.idAnimal = doacoes.idAnimalDoacao WHERE animais.idAnimal = doacoes.idDoacao;
```

Eu quero deletar uma **DOACAO**, onde o **ANIMAL** seja deletado ao mesmo tempo.

**Fica dando esse erro:**

> ```
> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.
> ```

Comment: Isso ta acontecendo no mysql. Como seria o codigo?

Comment: Como está o relacionamento entre as tabelas doacoes e animais? As cláusulas UPDATE CASCADE  e DELETE CASCADE não atenderiam a suas necessidades?

Comment: É porque eu sou novo nessa area. Tenho a tabela Doacao e Animal. Quando eu adiciono um animal, o ID do animal vai para a tabela DOACAO como idAnimalDoacao, assim criando uma doacao

Comment: Você está utilizando qual banco de dados? MySQL ou SQL Server? No comentário você se referiu ao MySQL mas sua pergunta está marcada como `sql-server`, corrija a informação!

Comment: Estou utilizando o MySQL. Desculpa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu SQL você está referenciando os campos chaves na clausula `ON` e novamente no `WHERE`.

Tente colocar no `WHERE` alguma validação como por exemplo

```
DELETE doacoes, animais 
  FROM doacoes 
 INNER JOIN animais ON animais.idAnimal = doacoes.idAnimalDoacao 
 WHERE doacoes.idDoacao = 13
```

Comment: Com esse, ta dando erro na FK

Comment: Modifiquei a resposte, tente novamente. Obs.: Estou sem acesso ao MySQL agora.

Comment: Consegui deletar fazendo assim
DELETE doacoes, animais 
  FROM doacoes 
 INNER JOIN animais ON animais.idAnimal = doacoes.idAnimalDoacao 
 WHERE doacoes.idDoacao = 13

Comment: Maravilha! Eu havia invertido as tabelas do `where` sem querer, vou ajustar a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Deve estar no modo safe do mysql tente executar isso.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
DELETE doacoes,animais FROM doacoes INNER JOIN animais WHERE animais.idAnimal = doacoes.idDoacao;
```

Comment: Não deletou, mas o codigo executou

Comment: editei, tente novamente com esse acima, caso não der teste usando INNER JOIN ao inves de LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: Não funcionou :/ 
Acho que fiz a query errada.